# Как писать правильно написать SqlCmdText в IsRecord?

Tags: sql

Ребята выручайте. есть запрос по типу

```
var o = 124;
var ox = nameTable.IsRecord(new SqlCmdText("O", o)).ToString();
```

но запрос не полный и наверное не хватает where?!
студия пишет https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmBhl.png

как правильно написать такой запрос?

Comment: Показанный код не имеет никакого отношения к SQL. Укажите язык программирования (и, если есть, используемый фреймворк/библиотеку).

Comment: да) уже разобралась) пишеться так .IsRecord(new SqlCmdText("O=@O", new SqlParam("O", o))